# Is there a quiet way to take out a drone without causing the enemies to start searching?

Tags: wolfenstein-2-the-new-colossus

Throughout the game, there are many flying drones that can spot you and alert the rest of the Nazis.  I'm finding it difficult to move pass them, and even more difficult to take them down without causing the rest of the nearby enemies to begin searching the area.

Are there any effective ways to take these drones out without causing the nearby enemies to start searching for me?

Comment: Wait until it gets away from the enemy group and spray with silenced SMG. If you are lucky, it will fall away from other enemies, far enough to not cause alarm. Throwing axes at them is pretty much useless as far as I can tell.

Comment: @MrScapegrace I was able to kill one with one throwing ax, the problem was it exploded and everyone heard it.

Answer (score 2):

If you stay out of range of them seeing you (30-40 yards, or slightly larger than your sight set while ADS) and give em about 7 rounds with the silenced handgun they dont realize whats going on. Still gotta hope they blow away from other enemies though